# Pulling out JSON data with src

Tags: javascript, json, src

I am trying to pull out the data with `src="";` and load it into variable but with no success.

Here is the code i have been working with:

```js
var JSONObject = document.getElementById("data").innerHTML;
console.log(JSONObject);
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.instagram.com/xsolvesoftware/media/' id="data"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`innerHTML` means exactly what it says: the inner HTML. It is the HTML between `<script>` and `</script>` of which there isn't any.

If you want to read the JS then you need to `getAttribute('src')` and then make an HTTP request for it (e.g. with `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`).

The Same Origin Policy will probably block this.

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: @AESTHETICS — You don't. See the last line of the answer. (Otherwise you shouldn't have any trouble finding documentation on `getAttribute` and `XMLHttpRequest`. They aren't obscure).

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is getting blocked and getAttribute is giving me only link itself to the page which is from src='https://www.instagram.com/xsolvesoftware/media/' using document.getElementById("data").getAttribute('src') to print https://www.instagram.com/xsolvesoftware/media/ with console.log();

Comment: "XMLHttpRequest is getting blocked" — See the last line of the answer. I said that would probably happen.

Comment: "getAttribute is giving me only link itself to the page" — Obviously. I said *and* not *or*. `getAttribute` is how you know what URL to pass to XMLHttpRequest (but as I said, the Same Origin Policy blocks your access to that URL).

Comment: @AESTHETICS — What you want is impossible to achieve with client side code. That's the best answer you are going to get.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is possible.

Comment: @AESTHETICS — [The usual limitations and work arounds apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068)